# Lightweight MS Paint/MacPaint equivalent FLOSS in Linux?

Tags: software-rec, image-editor, lightweight, free-software

What is an equivalent to MS Paint and MacPaint that works on Linux? There is a BSD-licenced one called [Paintbrush](http://paintbrush.sourceforge.net/) that's great for Mac OS X, but I have not found one on Linux.

I hope it can be lightweight, i.e. few dependencies, don't need GNOME, KDE, etc., but anything is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MyPaint](http://mypaint.intilinux.com/) is my favorite alternative to MSpaint.

[image: MyPaint screen-shot]

Answer (score 4):

- [Tux Paint](http://tuxpaint.org/), as mentioned in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/7786)
- [KolourPaint](http://www.kde.org/applications/graphics/kolourpaint/)

  [image: KolourPaint screen-shot]

Comment: +1 for kolourpaint, it's a real *old mspaint* clone.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what you're using this for, [TuxPaint](http://tuxpaint.org/) might fit the bill. It's designed for children and my kids find it fun to use.

[image: TuxPaint screen-shot]

Answer (score 1):

Another one:

- [mtPaint](http://mtpaint.sourceforge.net/) (GTK+, GPL, GitHub...)

[image: mtPaint screenshot]

(This one reminds me of my old dark Amiga 500 ages :))